# There are no commands defined in the "backup" namespace

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, mysql-backup

I have tried installing Laravel Backup for Database [paulvl/backup](https://github.com/paulvl/backup)

I have followed the instructions on how to install and configure it to my Laravel application. I am however stuck at the point where you actually run the backup command. I get this error:

```
$ php artisan backup:mysql-dump               
[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]
There are no commands defined in the "backup" namespace.
```

Any help would highly be appreciated

Here is the provider array in config/app.php
[image: Provider Array in config/app.php]

Answer (score 1):

From [the package docs](https://github.com/paulvl/backup):

> Once the package's installation completes, the final step is to add the service provider. Open `config/app.php`, and add a new item to the `providers` array:

```
Backup\BackupServiceProvider::class,
```

These commands will be automatically registered since the `BackupServiceProvider` [does that](https://github.com/paulvl/backup/blob/master/src/BackupServiceProvider.php#L25):

```
public function register()
{
    $this->registerMysqlDumpCommand();
    $this->registerMysqlRestoreCommand();
}
```

Comment: Hey Alexey. Thanks for the quick response. I was able to add Service to the provider and published the vendor. I am confused on why this error is actually popping up

Comment: @ChrisOtaalo try to clear config cache with `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: Tried that as well but didn't help